# Calling update_user_meta inside of another function doesn't work

Tags: database, user-meta

I have a function that does updates a db outside of wordpress and then I'd like it to take that information and update the user_meta table in wordpress.  The print statement prints all the appropriate information, but the update doesn't happen.

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'EditUsertoSF_Admin');

function EditUsertoSF_Admin($user_id) {
   global $SFUserID;

  $query = "SELECT Id, COUNT(Email) from Contact where Email='" . $_POST['email'] . "' GROUP BY ID";

            $createResponse3 = $mySforceConnection->query(($query));

            foreach ($createResponse3->records as $record) {
                foreach($record as $records) {
                    }
            }
                if($records > 0) {
                    $sObject->Id = $record->Id[0];
                    $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->update(array($sObject), 'Contact');

                    $SFUserID = $record->Id[0];
                    //print 'SF inside function Edit' . 'WP' . $user_id . 'SF' .$record->Id[0];
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'SF_User_ID', $SFUserID );
                }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how that could work. `$record` is not defined inside the function nor is a `global` pulled in. That variable should be out of scope.

Comment: sorry .. I added the rest of the code from the function

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?